# avoke meaning by using other words' definition

Tags: meaning

Can somebody write the 
  **another definition to the word  *avoke*** 
other than:  *call from or back again*? 
[I can't understand this expression, can somebody explain to me the expression by another expression with a example to use the word]?

Comment: here did you encounter this word?. I don't think it's one that most native speakers are familiar with today. All the dictionaries I found listing it online mark it as "obsolete".

Comment: It is not a commonly used word today. Also, it is easy to confuse with "evoke", which means to bring something to mind

Comment: I can't find it in *any* dictionary!

Comment: This is not an English word that I have ever come across, and I am a native English speaker of almost 70 years.

Comment: Evoke? Revoke? Invoke?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a Native speaker, and I do not recognise this word. I also agree that the definition is hard to understand. I finally got a clue from this related definition in [WordSense](https://www.wordsense.eu/avoke/)

```
avocate (English)
Verb
avocate (third-person singular simple present avocates, present participle avocating, simple past and past participle avocated)
(obsolete) To call off or away; to withdraw; to transfer to another tribunal.
```

I am guessing that avoke relates to hunting with a pack of dogs. If we want the pack to stop chasing something we

```
call the pack off
```

if the pack has raced ahead of the hunting party we

```
call the pack back
```

So we

```
avoke the pack
```

I note that avocate has a legal meaning, to transfer a case to another tribunal. So an alternative guess is that **avoke** may mean to ask that a case be withdrawn from a court, we call the case back from the court.

```
I wish to avoke my case
```

I must emphasise that these are guesses. If you ever encounter a usage of the word then you may be able to infer the meaning more definitively. I don't advocate the use of avoke in your own speech or writing, I doubt that you will be understood.